# Cannot connect to Team project collection

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins and am trying to set up the team project collection. My servername is:

```
http://<server-name>/tfs/Development%20and%20CFS%20UK/
```

I've left the last bit in so you can see it has spaces.

I'm adding the Jenkins credentials as:

Domain: Global credentials (it won't let me choose anything else)
Kind: Username with Password
Username: my windows domain\username used to access TFS
Password: my windows password used to access TFS
ID/Description, not sure whether these are important - assume not!

The error I receive is as follows:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The SOAP endpoint http://<server-name>/tfs/Development%20and%20CFS%20UK/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 502
```

If I cut and paste the url above into a browser it appears fine, with the following message:

```
Team Foundation Registration web service

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

GetRegistrationEntries
```

Comment: Error 502 means Bad Gateway (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error). Have you tried connecting to TFS URL using a browser from the Jenkins machine?

Comment: `I've left the last bit in so you can see it has spaces.` What's the detail mean of this ?Did you mean your tfs project collection has a space in the url?

Comment: Yes, see above. TFS is on a different server on the network, Jenkins is running on my local machine and I can access the url in a browsers from local. There is a space %20 in the collection url.

Answer (score 0):

The login name is important which must **contain the name of domain and user.**

> For [on-premises] Team Foundation Server, the User name can be
>   specified in two ways:
>
> - EXAMPLE-DOMAIN\user
> - user@domain.example.com

Suggest you to use the latest [Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) in Jenkins, more details of the job configuration, you can check the [release note](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

To narrow down if the space of your team project collection cause the issue, you could give a try with another collection url without space.

---

Update

If you copy the collection url in browser, it should link to a TFS web portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I've updated to specify that I used a username of form EXAMPLE-DOMAIN\user. I don't have a collection here that I can add which doesn't have a space in it. The TFS server is not managed by me and I'm running Jenkins on my local machine.

Comment: @kayakpim I guess you are using the wrong url. The URL to the [Team Project Collection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/manage-team-project-collections), for on-premise TFS should be something like this `http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection` the last should be the collection name such as DefaultCollection. However `Development%20and%20CFS%20UK` this looks like not a collection name. And if you copy the url in browser, it should link to a web portal such as the screenshot in my update answer. Please double check this with your TFS admin.

Comment: If you read the original message you'll see I'm posting the url from the error message, the collection url returns the portal above and I use it all the time. @Patrick, this is the correct collection name in this case, I've tried to access DefaultCollection and it exists but I don't have access to it.

Comment: @kayakpim I create a test with a new collection name including space. And enter the url  with  `http://myserver:8080/tfs/Projets%20Test` it works perfectly. If you are also using %20 escape the space such as `Development and CFS and UK` in the url, then this issues seems not related to url itself. Back to the error info  I think 502 is the key of figuring out the issue.  Some info related to [502 Bad Gateway](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939) Are you using any proxy in your Internet environment and try to disable the firewall for a test.

Comment: yes I had thought that there might be a network/firewall/proxy issue. Chance of getting IT to disable anything quickly is about 0 so I might be stuck...Thanks

Comment: Update this was caused by a blanket update to all repositories to all users which we were not notified of. We've resolved the issue now...